# Cash-or-Nothing Call Option

Tags: black-scholes, call, cash-or-nothing

I am trying to price a cash or nothing call option and I know know that the Cash or Nothing formula for a call option is $C(t,s)=Xe^{-r(T-t)}*N(d)$

If I have payoff X=100 r=0.03 T=2 $\sigma=0.3$

I would have $C(t,s)=100e^{-0.03(2-t)}N(d)$

but how would I find $N(d)$ and (T-t)as  where $$
d=\dfrac{\ln(S/E)+(r-\sigma^2/2)(T-t)}{\sigma\sqrt{T-t}}
$$

to calculate the price at time 0

Comment: why not to replace $t$ by 0!!!!

Comment: Hi thank I managed to realise that one :) I should have been more specific wish my problem of actually calculating N(d)

Comment: @JacobMitch where is the problem with calculating $N(d)$?

Answer (score 0):

In your formula you have the following variables:

- t= 0, T = the maturity of the call option which is known.
- S is the spot value of the underlying asof t = 0 (today) which is known.
- E is the strike of the option which is known
- r and σ are known.

In other word all the variables are known and thus it's a straight forward formula to get N(d)